# Start a timer and reset it after 3 seconds

Tags: c++

I want to implement a **timer that starts if a condition is true**, after 3 seconds I want it to **reset the timer** and it shall not start to count untill the condition in the if-statement is true again. See my code below:

```
//--here I want to check if 3 sec has gone, and if yes, do something and reset it--
int duration;
std::clock_t start;

while (1) {
     //some things here

     for (something) {
          //some things happening here

         if (a Condition) {
              start = std::clock(); <- start the timer here
         }
     }
}
```

I will use this with a video stream (opencv), thats why I have the `while` loop in case you wonder. I have not succeeded with this after several tries.

I am able to start the timer but then I want to have an if-statement to check if 3 seconds has passed `duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` but I am still unable solve it (both to check if time has passed and then to reset it). Any ideas will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
const std::clock_t notrunning = (std::clock_t)(-1);

inline void checkTimerReset(std::clock_t &start)
{
  if (start != notrunning) {
    if (((std::clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) >= 3)
      start = notrunning;
  }
}

...

std::clock_t start = notrunning;

while (1) {
  some things here

  for (something) {
    some things happening here

    if (something) {
      if (start == notrunning) {
          start = std::clock();
      }
    }

    checkTimerReset(start);
  }

  checkTimerReset(start);
}
```